# Swig error- Error: Syntax error in input(2)

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have been trying to create a python wrapper for a c++ library. Swig is giving an error for this section of code, and I don't understand what is causing the error. Also I am new to using swig. The error it is giving me is "Syntax error in input(2)", also Here is the section of code.

```
typedef void (__cdecl *TSI_FUNCTION_CAMERA_CONTROL_CALLBACK) (int ctl_event, void*context);
typedef void (__cdecl *TSI_FUNCTION_CAMERA_CONTROL_CALLBACK_EX)  (int  ctl_event,      TSI_FUNCTION_CAMERA_CONTROL_INFO *ctl_event_info, void *context);
typedef void (__cdecl *TSI_FUNCTION_IMAGE_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK) (int  notification,   void *context);
typedef void (__cdecl *TSI_FUNCTION_IMAGE_CALLBACK)  (TsiImage *tsi_image, void *context);
typedef void (__cdecl *TSI_TEXT_CALLBACK_FUNCTION)  (char     *str,           void *context);
```

Comment: SWIG does not understand `__cdecl`. Add `%include "windows.i". You may have other symbols which are undefined, but from the information that you have given I cannot tell.

Comment: That fixed the error, thanks for the help.

Comment: I turned the fix into an answer, because I think this is a problem many developers run into.

Answer (score 3):

SWIG does not understand __cdecl. You possibly need to add `%include "windows.i" to your interface file. You may have other symbols, which are undefined, but from the information that you have given I cannot tell.

```
%module example
%{
  #include "example_if.h"
%}
...
# Here it must be present
%include "windows.i"
...
%include "example_if.h"
```